# How to display the percentage progress of BytesTotal / Filesize giving the code below

Tags: c#, percentage

The code below uploads a file to a FTP server and the variable numBytes always receives chunks of 512 bytes. The BytesTotal is the sum of these 512 bytes. So the percentage will calculate 512/total, 1024/total, etc... This works fine but it will display way too many lines.

I want Console.WriteLine to display a maximum of 10 lines saying: 10%, 20% ... 90%, 100%. 
How can I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
int percentComplete = 0;
long numBytes = ftp.DoUpload();
while (numBytes > 0)
{
    percentComplete = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * ftp.BytesTotal) / ftp.FileSize);
    Console.WriteLine("Bytes Transfered: " + percentComplete.ToString() + "%");
    numBytes = ftp.DoUpload();
}
ftp.Disconnect();
```

UPDATED Code:

```
private string PrintPercent2(long currentValue, long maxValue)
{
    string percentProgress = "0%";
    long oneTenth = (long)maxValue / 10;
    long[] percentIntervals = new long[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < percentIntervals.Length; i++) {
        percentIntervals[i] = oneTenth * (i + 1);
    }

    if (currentValue > percentIntervals[0] && currentValue < percentIntervals[1])
        percentProgress = "10%";
    else if (currentValue > percentIntervals[1] && currentValue < percentIntervals[2])
        percentProgress = "20%";
    else if (currentValue > percentIntervals[2] && currentValue < percentIntervals[3])
        percentProgress = "30%";
    else if (currentValue > percentIntervals[3] && currentValue < percentIntervals[4])
        percentProgress = "40%";
    else if (currentValue > percentIntervals[4] && currentValue < percentIntervals[5])
        percentProgress = "50%";
    else if (currentValue > percentIntervals[5] && currentValue < percentIntervals[6])
        percentProgress = "60%";
    else if (currentValue > percentIntervals[6] && currentValue < percentIntervals[7])
        percentProgress = "70%";
    else if (currentValue > percentIntervals[7] && currentValue < percentIntervals[8])
        percentProgress = "80%";
    else if (currentValue > percentIntervals[8] && currentValue < percentIntervals[9])
        percentProgress = "90%";
    else if (currentValue >= maxValue)
        percentProgress = "100%";

    return percentProgress;
}
```

Comment: Do you literally want "10, 20, 30...", or do you want 10 values, even if they are 11, 22.1, 30.05, etc.?

Comment: I want 10 values, no matter what they are. I tried using "if (percentComplete % 10 == 0)" but if the file is too big, the function will print 0% hundreds of times :(

Comment: I don't have time to write the code right now, but given that you've got 512 byte chunks and a known total size, you could test for the actual multiples of 512 that you expect at 1/10 intervals.

Comment: hey Jon, yes, I updated the code and it works except that I still need to show 10% only once, 20% only once and so on. I just built a very rudimentary logic :)

Comment: well I can add a Boolean to each interval and set to true once the value is displayed. That resolves my issue. I am sure there's a better way to do this but this is the way I know :-)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following program to help you out. Its a little hacky, but it works with every test I performed:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        string lastValue = "";

        long currentValue = 0;
        long maxValue = LongRandom(0, 1134984, rnd);
        while (currentValue <= maxValue)
        {
            lastValue = PrintProgress(currentValue, maxValue, lastValue);
            currentValue++;
        }
    }

    private static long LongRandom(long min, long max, Random rand)
    {
        var buf = new byte[8];
        rand.NextBytes(buf);
        long longRand = BitConverter.ToInt64(buf, 0);

        return (Math.Abs(longRand % (max - min)) + min);
    }

    private static string PrintProgress(long currentValue, long maxValue, string lastValue)
    {
        if (currentValue == 0)
            return "";
        decimal q = decimal.Multiply((decimal.Divide(currentValue, maxValue) - 1), 100);

        if (Math.Round(q, 0)%10 == 0)
        {
            string s = string.Format("{0}%", (Math.Abs(decimal.Subtract(Math.Abs(q), 100))).ToString("N0"));
            if (s == lastValue)
                return lastValue;
            if (s == "0%")
                return "0%";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return s;
        }

        return lastValue;
    }
```

You only need to copy out the `PrintProgress` function. The other stuff was just for me to test it out.

Answer (score -1):

Jusy add if((percentComplete % 10 )== 0) before your WriteLine

Comment: that won't work well. I get results like 20,70,90,100%. I was trying to split the total file size in 10 and then display the percentage based on the chunk of bytes I have transferred.Basically, I wanted to user to see 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100%